# Chrome: jQuery .height issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, height

I have been looking into this issue for some time now but could not find any solution.

**Case:**

I have an iframe which I need to re-size according to content (the page is AJAX intensive and content can increase and decrease as per users actions). As both the parent page and the one loading in iframe are on the same domain I have written a js function in parent page, which expects an integer value. And then sets the height of iframe through js as mentioned below.

```
document.getElementById('frameId').style.height = (height) + "px";
```

**Issue:**

I am using jQuery to get the height of the document when it changes.

```
jQuery(document).height();
```

The issue that I encountered was that Chrome was giving me height about 300px more than the Firefox/IE. I was looking into why this was happening. And after banging my head around I found that in Chrome for some reason when I am getting height of document it also includes in calculation those elements whose "display" setting in css is set to "none". I have a list that displays when a user makes an action. And now it is creating problem in my calculations. Due to this extra height that I am getting the page looks empty at the bottom and it feels as if something has not loaded yet (which is not very appealing).

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Jehanzeb

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? Some older versions do have some issues concerning height evaluation.

Comment: Have tested on "24.0.1312.56 m"  and  "24.0.1312.57 m".

Comment: Did you try : `$('#frameId').height( $(document).innerHeight() );`

Comment: No. Let me test and see if it works.

Comment: I asked for your jQuery version - not your chrome version...

Comment: Sorry for that. I am currently working with 1.8
@adeneo That seems to have solved the problem. But got another slight issue. When the I click on button to show the list the size of iframe increases fine. But when I close the list (set display: none using jQuery) the page does not get back to initial height. Although I am calling resize after I use jQuery addClass which is to my knowledge synchronous. But I will look in to it. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @adeneo If you can add this as an answer I can select it as valid answer.

Comment: Sure, added an answer. Not sure I get the second problem, what are you calling resize on exactly ?

Comment: When I click on the button to close the list what happens is that a class is removed from the list "display-block" (which as name suggests has the setting of display: block) and another class is added named "display-none". Why I am not simply using .hide or .show is because they have an issue in IE9. So after I add class "display-none" I call the parent function and as an argument send the current height of document so that iframe height can be set relatively. 

`parent.resizeIframe(jQuery(document).innerHeight());`

But I am getting the same height as if the list was open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try:

```
$('#frameId').height( $(document).innerHeight() );
```